# Android Studio подвисание из-за использования MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

При использовании MotionLayout происходит зависание Android Studio секунд на 10-20.

Это может быть открытие Xml с этим Layout.
Попытка изменить что-то в Design и т.д.

Как можно исправить?
Упор в оперативную памяти нет (свободно более 8 GB)

Comment: возможно баг в студии

Comment: @Andrew и да, переустановка не помогает

Comment: тогда баг, была как-то проблема с редактором разметки ее вроде починили, это думаю тоже такого рода баг, попробуйте увеличить объем выделяемой памяти